# 2013 Workflows always set approval status to draft

Tags: 2010, 2013, workflow

I have a "**pages**" library in a publishing site and I have to use a workflow to fetch some information to compose some part of the page. Therefore I would like to set this workflow to start at any item change. 
The workfow works fine, but then when I approve the page for publishing, **SP takes it as a change** and starts again the workflow (that is not a problem) and sets the approval status again to draft.
Does anybody can suggest a workaround to avoid this? I see that any 2013 workflow - as they are started - set the approval status to draft. 2010 workflows did not do it (but for my purposes I cannot use 2010 workflows).

Comment: Unfortunately I see there is not workaround for it. WF in 2013 are structured so that they set the item to draft as they are started on one side, on the other side the feature "changing an item will start the workflow" get activated also on status change and there is not granular options in OOB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there is not workaround for it... WF in 2013 are structured so that they set the item to draft as they are started. Moreover the feature "changing an item will start the workflow" get activated also on status change and there is not granular option in OOB to set e g the workflow to start at certain conditions.